# Programmatically Printing or converting a powerpoint to one note

Tags: c#, ms-office, powerpoint, onenote

Hello I want to create an application which will make things easier for me.
I always need to convert a bunch of power point documents to one note, but the process takes a few minutes for each. The process goes as follows:


1.)I have to open the powerpoint and then print>Print to Onenote.

2.)Then once Onenote opens I have to, file>save as>Page> Onenote 2007 Section.


I want create an application that will allow me to be able to browse for a PowerPoint file and then have all the slides from the PowerPoint file to be converted into a one note page and then saved in One note 2007 format.

I have experience programming using C#.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple thing you can try is to use [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx).

If that is not good enough, you can do the full [Office interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsto/default.aspx) story.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but using SendKeys how would I select the printer as Send to Onenote and then save it as a 2007 section from there?

I think I would have to read more on Office interop, but there is nothing on onenote.